# How to fill half of a fragment with another layout in android?

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments

I have a fragment with a button at the top. The fragment also has a full screen image.Lets assume my fragment into two halves (i.e the top half and bottom half). So my button is at the top half of the fragment.

Now what I want is when I click on the button at the top half of the fragment, I need to show some other UI at the bottom half of the fragment. But my top half should be visible and interactive. So that when I click again on the button at the top half again this new layout closes.

Comment: Simply create a linear layout file for your fragment including weights. Set the orientation to vertical. The weightsum to 1 , weight of the button to 0.5 and also the weight of the other view to 0.5. Height of both of them to 0dp. Then you simply set the visibility of your view to VISIBLE or INVISIBLE (not to GONE)

Comment: ^ and change visibility accordingly..

Comment: "when I click on the button at the top half of the fragment at
the bottom half I need" it has no sense

Comment: Other option you can use framelaout and update this with new fragment .

Comment: I can do that but the problem is my top half of the fragment should not get shrink. It should remain the same and act lik something has been kept on top of it